# Create DeepOmit type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a `DeepOmit` type. The goal is to `Omit` a certain key recursively on a type.

This is what I have so far:

```
type DeepOmit<T, K extends keyof any> = Omit<
  {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends object
      ? DeepOmit<T[P], K>
      : T[P] extends (infer T1)[]
      ? DeepOmit<T1, K>[]
      : T[P];
  },
  K
>;
```

It works for interface `TestA`:

```
interface TestA {
  propA: number;
  propB: {
    propA: number;
    propX: string;
  };
  propC:
    | {
        propA: number;
        propX: string;
      }[];
}

const testA: DeepOmit<TestA, 'propA'> = {
  propB: {propX: 'test'},
  propC: [{propX: 'test'}],
};
```

But it does not work for `TestB` `propC`:

```
interface TestB {
  propA: number;
  propC?:
    | ({
        propA: number;
        propX: string;
      } | null)[] | null;
}

const testB: DeepOmit<TestB, 'propA'> = {
  propC: [{propX: 'test'}],
};
```

Error: `Property 'propA' is missing in type '{ propsX: string; }' but required in type '{ propA: number; propsX: string; }'.`

Is this doable?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=7&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhFgPIFsCWwA8AVANFA0lBAB7AQB2AJgM5QDWEIA9gGZQCG5IAfFALxQU6DACgoUAN5jxUANoAFKKnL1GrKFgC6ALg0LNRUhRpQmAIwBWEAMbBpMqAH5Y8JGkxZ9efN3szdnvIGJGRUtAAUyiwQAE4aAIwAlLKafuLOcAhCHvHe3ClpUAH6ANzSAL440vgi3GUiymQxLOzW0FgQ1MAAgpLSYDFMYN265ACuyGaxZeIDQwBCulIOc8OjE1MxMzKrABq6XTHKAObb5durAMLafgA+fQ4rg2tQ45PThbPP+1CHJ9sOcopMrlEQiaxMchdKBkLojFxZdzYTo9PAAclW3TRvAEyygq0Wkj2ujRsOAaMq-We1zkEmJUFJKIpmiq5zBjViLTaGhR8we+Oe8Lemwu1McNwc93CeMeAqGQo2H1lXyGPz+5FOhXKUHu4wANnrkgZdWMDSCwRCocAYbzdJk3MIOl15ujMdj+PyrrpZHTviSyczWSUgA)

Comment: You can find a working implementation in ts-essentials: https://github.com/krzkaczor/ts-essentials#DeepOmit

Comment: Their implementation doesn't actually do what I want. They required you to specify down the tree all the props you want to omit. I want to omit the same key recursively.